# NSOutlineView : Expand all objects of a specific class only

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

What's the most efficient way to expand all objects of a specific class in a `NSOutlineView`? (The datasource of my outline view is a `NSTreeController`).

Let's say I have

```
classA
classA
    - classA
        - classC
        - classC
    - classB
        - classC
        - classC
classB
   - classC
```

I want to expand classA objects only. Do I need to iterate through the entire tree checking which class belong each object?

**UPDATE**
Sorry I have to make a correction. The outlineView objects are NSTreeNodes from NSTreeController data source. And only the "representedObject" are those my custom classes.

So the structure with those classes is correct, but they are not directly accessible as nodes of the outline view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, the important "glue" I mentioned in the comment is more or less straight from this great blog post: [Saving the expand state of a NSOutlineView](http://gibbston.net/?p=4).

I took all the classes in my tree, and made them subclasses of an abstract class with an `expanded` property, so every `representedObject` in an `NSTreeNode` has `expanded` as a property.

But you may not even need to do that if you don't care about persisting `expanded` in your data model.

The straightforward thing to do is to just iterate the rows:

```
    for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < [outlineView numberOfRows]; row++)
    {
        // Expand item if it's an classA
        NSTreeNode* treeNode = [outlineView itemAtRow:row];
        if ([treeNode.representedObject isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]])
            [sender.animator expandItem:treeNode];
    }
```

... you'll notice that for loop borrows a lot of structure from the referenced blog post.

So I guess my answer is a lazy, "yes, iterate the whole tree."  At least the displayed tree.

*EDIT:*  For those who are a bit overzealous about MVC, I now feel it's necessary to specify that the above code should be in the class you use as the `NSOutlineView` controller, which would usually implement `<NSOutlineViewDelegate>`

Comment: Sorry I have to make a correction. The outlineView objects are NSTreeNodes from NSTreeController data source. And only the "representedObject" are those my custom classes. So I can't add any property to these objects, because I don't subclass the nodes.

Comment: @Patrick - Just iterating the rows is the simple thing, so with the bounty you ought to specify O(rows) doesn't cut it.    I still think the NSTreeNode wrapper is no great hurdle for the above, but I have to go squint at my old code for the glue.

Comment: @stevesliva unfortunately, the link is now broken

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for NSOutlineViewDelegate:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
{
    if ([[item representedObject] isMemberOfClass:[ClassA class]]) {
        [outlineView expandItem:item];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Do I need to iterate through the entire tree checking which class belong each object?

Yes, because that is, what you want to do.

But it is not that easy as in the A of stevesliva:

A. You should not iterate over the items of the outline view. It is a view. It has nothing to do with the data. I. e., if a node is closed, the descendants are *not* in the row list. This is because there is no row for them.

B. Instead iterate over the content of the tree controller. Controllers are made for data access, so it is the right place to access data. `-arrangedObjects` (`NSTreeController`) gives you access to the content.

Comment: It is as easy as stevesilva's answer because there's no indication the OP wants to expand nodes which *contain* `classA` objects, just expands those which *are* `classA` objects. If a `classA` object is inside of a `classB` object which is collapsed, it doesn't matter if that `classA` object is "expanded" or "collapsed". That has no particular meaning. So, it's sufficient to walk the rows and expand the ones you come across which are `classA`.

Comment: There is an indication: "to expand **all** objects of a specific class". Beside this, it is a methodically wrong approach to ask a view for the data as mentioned.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - I think you handcuff yourself unnecessarily if you think you can't query a view when trying to efficiently modify the view and not the model.  It's akin to declaring you can't just delete all a view's subviews with view hierarchy code, which would be ridiculous. Controllers have weak ownership of their view outlets explicitly because the views take ownership of the view hierarchy, and you're most certainly allowed to traverse the view hierarchy when you're changing what is displayed.

Comment: The change of the view depends on the data in the model, in this case the type of the data. So you have to ask the model. You do this via the controller. It's pretty simple MVC. Deleting subviews in a view does not depend of the data in the model. You can do it in the view layer. So you can traverse wherever you want, but if you need `[underlyingData somewhat]` you have to ask the controller. (You can do this from the view with cocoa bindings, but it is akin of useless.) As mentioned your approach will at least fail, if you have to check for data actually not displayed.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - this code would be *in the controller*, at least whatever class implemented the delegate methods for the outlineview.  You can have both that *and* a treeController, you know.  I'm not suggesting that the code snippet provided be included in a subclass of the outlineview, because yeah, it's ugly to subclass the view to check `isKindOfClass`... but it's ***standard*** for the class implementing NSOutlineViewDelegate  to query both the state of the view and interrogate the model objects.

Comment: Exactly: The posted code resides inside a (control flow) controller. And then it (= the code in the controller) asks the view(!) for the data of the model! Don't you see, how weird this is?Beside this it would be no problem to place the code inside a category of the view. (You con't need a subclass.) But even if it is placed there, the code should ask the (data flow) controller (data source or binding) for the data and not ask itself. It would be the same misconcept on a different layer. If you want to have data, ask the controller for it. From the view layer and from the controller layer.

Comment: The view layer holds a possibly edited and possibly transformed and possibly partial and possibly $whatever copy the data for and only for displaying. It does not hold the original data. So do not use it.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - no, it's not "weird" for a VC to use a view's instance methods.  The view's got the metadata that only it has appended to the model objects about their view state.

Comment: No, that is not weird. But it is, if the VC uses view's instance methods to get the data. It is completely upside down. And the class of an data item is definitely a property of the data and no state in the view. If you have many independent views, displaying the data, the class would always be the same.

Comment: However, this is that fundamental knowledge that I really do not see any benefit in giving more beginner's lessons.